End of Month Switch Option calculation in Burghardt's Treasury Bond Basis
Burghardt, in his book, outlines the way one can value the government bond basis and value its richness/cheapness.
The steps are the following:

Calculate historical betas for yield changes
Create a bump-matrix where yields are bumped in different directions
Calculate prices of all bonds in the delivery basket for each bump scenario
Dividing each bond's price net of carry by the conversion factor.
For each scenario, the bond with the lowest converted price will be the CTD
He calculates, for each scenario, a future price 'by assuming that the net basis equals the value of the end-of-month switch option
'Armed with this hypothetical future price, the net basis is calculated for all the non-cheap bonds'

My issue is with point 6. How is the 'value of the end-of-month' switch option calculated? He doesn't explain how to do this in the book. One practitioner told me that, because this is a circular problem, they just take the converted price to be the future price - and calculate the net basis from there - however I'm not convinced.
Thank you

This is not an answer, I am also curious to hear good ways to calculate the value of this option. What the practitioner suggests, implies a 0 value for the EOM option, which is probably not a bad assumption at the moment, but can be when that option is in play/valuable.
